# How to automate TFS to build xamarin.iOS

Tags: ios, tfs, xamarin

I would like to automate a build process of my Xamarin.iOS project.  Do I need to have Visual Studio installed on the server with TFS?  Is there anything special that needs to be done to point to the mac build host?  Or do I need to copy files to the mac build host and initiate the build there and then copy it back to the TFS Server?

Comment: have you read the docs?  https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/ci/tfs_walkthrough/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to install VS on TFS server and configure the TFS to connect to Mac Build Host. Refer to following links for details:

[Configuring Team Foundation Server for Xamarin - Requirement](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/ci/configuring_tfs/#Requirements)

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/ci/configuring_tfs/connect-tfs-xamarin/

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio online now has build definitions for Xamarin.iOS so you can build on the cloud.

Sign up for an account, create a project, go to build > build definitions > + > select Xamarin.iOS.

Not a lot of documentation on it but if you work it out, its great.

Comment: Have you gotten the Xamarin.iOS build to work in VSTS? I'm running into some odd issues and can't find much help here or anywhere else.

Comment: I would suggest checking the VSTS tasks GitHub repo (https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks) and asking one of he guys on there.  They were very helpful last time I had an issue.